# JPA - insert into select - copy large amount of records

Tags: jpa, jpql, named-query

I would like to copy records with diffrent key values. what is the best way to do so ?
In plain sql I would do:

```
insert into tableX values (x1,x2,x3,x4,x5) select 2,T1.x2,T1.x3,T1.x4,T1.x5 from tableX T1
```

(x1 is my primary key).
I tried writing this code inside the entity `@NamedQuery`, but i got `org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.JPQLException` and after searching a way to write it i understand that this sql cannot be wriitten inside `NamedQuery` - is that correct?

I also tried looping through the object list representing tableX and for every object I did `em.find()` or created a new object and then inserted it with `em.persist` - but it seems to be an inefficient way. (when using find I do a select for each object , so if i have a list of 2000 records, it dosent make sense to create 2000 selectes and then insert with new key value).

So my question is what is the best way to implement copying all the records? 
also if I got an exception, or something went wrong I would like to rollback so that I wont have only part of the records inside my database table.

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use any SQL in JPA through a native query.  SQL would be best for this type of insert.

If you need to do anything in Java on the data before inserting it, then you would query the objects, then insert them.  Enable batch writing to improve efficiency.

http://java-persistence-performance.blogspot.com/2013/05/batch-writing-and-dynamic-vs.html